# form validation error handing with jQuery and PHP, PHP not loading

Tags: php, jquery

I'm working on a form validation with jQuery and PHP, currently using the AJAX jquery method. PHP file doesn't show up in the Networks tab in the browser developer console. I debugged my code and couldn't see where it went wrong.

Can you guys please give me a few pointers to where I missed out in my code?

HTML

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
            <h1 class="display-4 form-heading col-md-9">Now's the time to adopt a <span class="highlight">better</span> email security solution</h1>
            <p class="form-copy col-md-9">Let us help you migrate and enhance your email security.</p>
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="inputFirstName">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="inputFirstName" name="FirstName" placeholder="333333" required>


              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="inputLastName">Last Name:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" name="LastName" placeholder="Last Name" required>

              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputEmail">Email Address:</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="Email" placeholder="aaa" required>
              <div class="form-valid-feedback" id="email-error"></div>
            </div>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){


        $('form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
     //beginning AJAX
     function checkEmail(email){
       var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
       return re.test(email);
     }
     function checkPhoneNumber(phone){
       var phonePattern = /^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/;
       return phonePattern.test(phone);
     }
     var FirstName = $("#inputFirstName").val();
     var LastName = $("#nputLastName").val();
     var email = $("#inputEmail").val();
     var companyName = $("#inputCompanyName").val();
     var phone = $("#inputPhone").val();
     var submit = $("#inputsubmit").val();

     var formData = {
       FirstName : $("#inputFirstName").val(),
       LastName : $("#nputLastName").val(),
    email : $("#inputEmail").val(),
    companyName : $("#inputCompanyName").val(),
       phone : $("#inputPhone").val(),
       submit: $("#inputsubmit").val()
     };
     $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url : 'process.php',
       data:formData
     })


       if(!data.success){
         if(data.errors.firstName){
           $(".form-valid-feedback").show();
           $(".form-valid-feedback").html(data.errors.firstName);
         }
         if(data.errors.LastName){
           $(".form-valid-feedback").show();
           $(".form-valid-feedback").html(data.errors.LastName);
         }
         if(data.errors.email){
           $(".form-valid-feedback").show();
           $(".form-valid-feedback").html(data.errors.email);
         }
         if(data.errors.CompanyName){
           $(".form-valid-feedback").show();
           $(".form-valid-feedback").html(data.errors.CompanyName);
         }
         if(data.errors.Phone){
           $(".form-valid-feedback").show();
           $(".form-valid-feedback").html(data.errors.Phone);
         }


       }
       else if(!checkEmail(email)){
         $(".form-valid-feedback").show();
         $(".form-valid-feedback").html('Please enter a vlid email address: example@example.com');
       }
       else if (!checkPhoneNumber(phone)){
         $(".form-valid-feedback").show();
         $(".form-valid-feedback").html('Please enter a vlid Phone Number: 333-333-3333');
       }
       else{
         $('form').append('<div class="alert alert-success" id="success">' + data.message + '</div>');
       }
     })
     .fail(function(data){
       console.log(data)
     });

    });

    //end of submit event handling


});
```

PHP

```
<?php

  $errors = array();
  $data = array();

  //starting the validation of variables
  if (empty($_POST['FirstName']))
    $errors['FirstName'] = "First Name is required.";

  if (empty($_POST['LastName']))
      $errors['LastName'] = "Last Name is required.";

  if (empty($_POST['Email']))
        $errors['Email'] = 'Email is required.';

  if (empty($_POST['CompanyName']))
      $errors['CompanyName'] = 'Company Name is required.';


  if (empty($_POST['Phone']))
      $errors['Phone'] = 'Phone Number is required.';

  if(! empty($errors)) {
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors'] = $errors;
  }

  else{
    //when everything is free of errors

    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Success!';


  }

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: You made a typo here `#nputLastName`.

Comment: Consider adding a `success` handler to your ajax then either log to the console or `alert()` the response: the error will display or other problematic result for you to inspect coming from your `process.php`.